# How to customize ActiveAdmin form for HABTM relationship in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, customization, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models `Trip` and `Attraction` for admin panel I have used [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin). Now while creating new trip from activeadmin I wished to add user can select multiple `Attractions` and it's data should be stored in another table called **`trip_attractions`** (`:trip_id , :attraction_id`)

Here is my model:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to :attractions
end

class Attraction < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :trips
end

class TripAttraction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips
  has_many :attractions
end
```

and for **ActiveAdmin** form customization I tried in **app/admin/trip.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Trip do
.....
form multipart: true do |f|

f.inputs "Trip" do
 f.input :title
 f.input :description 
 # Here I want to show all attractions and as multiple select it should be stored in trip_attractions table
 f.input 'Attractions' do
  f.input :attractions, :as => :select, :multiple => true, collection: Attraction.all
 end
end
```

Where I do mistake? Please guide me how can I show all `attractions` on *new trip form* and on multiple select it should be stored in `trip_attractions` table. I really appreciate for your guideline and help. If you required more details then please feel free to ask.

**In addition** : I also tried to add `attraction_ids` field in trip table and in model I defined it as [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) to stored as an array of attraction's ids but I think it's not good approach as attraction may deleted it's id will remain in trip table. So I avoid this option and also not saved in database while submitting form. :(

Comment: Many questions: 1) What output are you getting?  2) Are you getting any errors when you do this? 3) Have you considered `has_many, through:` ? 4) What do your web server logs show for the queries when you view the page?

Comment: Please how this resolved? am facing a similar challenge